# Communcation between Web Components

Tags: javascript, web-component, native-web-component

I am building a project with web components and vanilla javascript.

I have a component/module called `meal.module` - It is the parent component of the components `meal-list` and `meal-search`.

- meal-list displays multiple meals from an api.
- meal-search contains an input field and seachterm as attribute.

**meal.module.js**

```
export default class MealModule extends HTMLElement {

    connectedCallback() {
        this.innerHTML = '<mp-meal-search searchterm=""></mp-meal-search> ' +
            '<mp-meal-list></mp-meal-list> ' +                
    }
}

if (!customElements.get('mp-meal-module')) {
    customElements.define('mp-meal-module', EssenModule);
}
```

**meal-list.component**

```
export default class MealListComponent extends HTMLElement {

   connectedCallback() {
       this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
       this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = Template.render();
       // Renders the meals from api into the template 
       this.getMeals();
   }

   (....) more code
}

if (!customElements.get('mp-meal-list')) {
    customElements.define('mp-meal-list', MealListComponent);
}
```

**meal-search.component**

```
export default class MealSearchComponent extends HTMLElement {

    static get observedAttributes() {
        return ['searchterm'];
    }

    attributeChangedCallback(name, oldVal, newVal) {
        if (name === 'searchterm') {
            this.doSearch();
        }
    }

    set searchTerm(val) {
        this.setAttribute('searchterm', val)
    }

    get searchTerm() {
        return this.getAttribute('searchterm');
    }

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="searchterm" value=""/>'

        this.shadowRoot.addEventListener('change', (event) =>
            this.searchTerm = event.target.value
        )
    }

    doSearch() {
        // send signal to MealListComponent for search
    }
}

if (!customElements.get('mp-meal-search')) {
    customElements.define('mp-meal-search', MealSearchComponent);
}
```

In the seach-component the SearchTerm is configured as Attribute. Everytime the input field gets changed, the attribute also changes.

Now I want to implement a "searchMeal" function, that always triggers when the attribute in MealSearchComponent changes.

I already tried to import the `MealSearchComponent` into the  MealListComponent. But it does seem to break the rule of components, not having any dependencies.

Comment: How many developers are going to work on this?

Comment: It's for a project in university @Danny'365CSI'Engelman (Topic: Web Components)

Comment: Separate files are great for large teams. If its just you, it is way easier to keep everything in one file. You have coupling already, the main file contains the names of all components, so individual components will never be distributed as single component. For these 3 coupled components, think of it as a box of Legos, components are the bricks. Communication between (isolated) components is best done with Events: https://open-wc.org/faq/events.html I presume this is the topic of your assignment. But IRL I would do this in one imported file (a closure) with helper functions

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I understand your point, but the child components aren't only search and list - there are more like add-component, delete-componenent, update-component etc. - I think all of this in one component would be a bit too much. It's my thesis exam. But I'll have a look at the custom events.

Comment: Then they want to see separation of concerns. Still means you can combine Components in one file if they are very closely related (actually, I would give my students a +1 if I see them do that wisely) [Events](https://open-wc.org/faq/events.html) is what you need for communication.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman - I have done this in the "parent component", in the post `meal.module` - is that what you mean? I'm not sure if it's a module or just a parent component.

Comment: Stick with what you got, concentrate on Events

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript from the outside of the shadow DOM can access the shadow DOM via the `element.ShadowRoot` property.